# I have to scroll the vertical bar to click the buttons in the modal-footer

Tags: html, css

I am using css bootstrap popup modal. In the popup modal-footer I have two buttons. To click any of the button either I have to scroll the verticalbar which is proesent in the modal itself not in the browser or in the app or I have to zoom in to small size instead of 100%. is ther way that I can click the buttons without scrolling the vertical bar or without changing the browser zoom.

```
<div class="modal modal-megamenu" id="dellmodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-megamenu">
        <div class="modal-content modal-megamenu">
            <div class="modal-header modal-megamenu">
                <h4 class="modal-title">scrollbar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body modal-megamenu">
                <div class="form-display">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rejectCheckbox" id="checkbox">
                    &nbsp
                <label>Hi click the button.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer modal-megamenu">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-button" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false"
                    type="submit">Reject</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end modal-content -->
    </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the css

```
.modal-footer {
height:50%;
}
```

same like the above lines I tried to change the modal-dialog,modal-title.
Nothing worked
[image]

As per the above image I want to click the buttons without using scroll bar or reduce the browser zoom.
can some one help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer for this
I have to include this in my css file

```
.modal-megamenu {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 400px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```